# Error 415 when trying to consume $http.post service from AngularJS to Spring MVC - Maven

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to check if a user exist when clicking on Login button migrating from `Spring Forms + JSTL + Spring MVC` to `AngularJS + Spring MVC`, but I'm getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Tipo de Medio No Soportado)

I'm new to AngularJS and Spring so be nice.

This is my Java Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("empleado")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private IServiceEmpleado serviceEmpleado;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login/check", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, produces={"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    public @ResponseBody void login(@RequestBody LoginDTO login, HttpSession session) throws ServicioException{


    Empleado empleado = serviceEmpleado.correctLogin(login.getDni(), login.getPassword());

    session.setAttribute("empleado", 

    empleado);

    }
}
```

This is my AngularJS controller:

```
angular.module('electronicaDonPepe')
    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', 
        function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {

        $scope.login = function(){
            var param = {
                    dni: $scope.usuario.dni, 
                    contrasenia: $scope.usuario.contrasenia
            };

            $http.post('http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/login/check', param).then(function(){
                $state.go('login');
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Finally, this is the error:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/login/check
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Tipo de Medio No Soportado
Remote Address:[::1]:8585
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-store
Content-Language:es
Content-Length:1120
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 19 Jan 2017 13:44:02 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:43
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=4E1E018490CC15F29FBE205132C2CACD; __ngDebug=true
Host:localhost:8585
Origin:http://localhost:8585
Referer:http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
view source
{dni: "34631248", contrasenia: "34631248"}
contrasenia
:
"34631248"
dni
:
"34631248"
```

And some AngularJS Batarang hints:

```
Module "ui.router.util" was created but never loaded.
Module "ui.router.router" was created but never loaded.
Module "ui.router.state" was created but never loaded.
Module "ui.router" was created but never loaded.
Module "ui.router.compat" was created but never loaded.
Module "electronicaDonPepe" was created but never loaded.
```

I did my research but it seems to be a very particular case in each example I read. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to set `Content-Type:application/json` ?

Comment: No, I will try and I'll let you know. Do you mean in the meta tag?

Comment: Yes.Set it in request header. I guess that is the error because your are accepting `application/json` and sending `text/html`

Comment: did it works for you ?

Comment: No, it didn't but the error changed to 500 - Internal server error.

Comment: That might be problem with your java code ? did you check the exceptions ?

Comment: Maybe there is but in the eclipse console I don't have any exceptions, I could see this error on Chrome Developers Tool. I have to keep searching in order to give a better response ... I need some time to clear my head. It's seems like a break up haha. Thanks for your time Dinesh I hope to come back with an answer.

Comment: It's hard to tell what wrong with out looking whole code now.You better try to send the request using REST Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{dni: "34631248", contrasenia: "34631248"}
```

Here is your Error. You are passing an invalid JSON format type. Try to use any formater online and you will see that it will give you and error.

```
{"dni": "34631248", "contrasenia": "34631248"}
```

This is the correct way of a Json Format Type. Hope it help you. Now the two are passing in strings.

```
  var param = {
                    "dni": $scope.usuario.dni, 
                    "contrasenia": $scope.usuario.contrasenia
            };
```

Then try with this.

Comment: Hi, I had some doubts on this suggestion but I tried it anyways. It still gives me the same error when I call the controller method. I saw examples from where I took the format type I used and it worked properly. Now I have the doubt... do you have some document I can verify the correct way of Json Format Type? I'm not able to find it on angularJS docs.

Comment: `view source
{dni: "34631248", contrasenia: "34631248"}
contrasenia
:
"34631248"
dni
:
"34631248"` This is the main error for me. Because you format that you are trying to pass is not a valid type. [Check this tutorial  I made an edit in my answer](https://geekytheory.com/json-i-que-es-y-para-que-sirve-json/)

Comment: Oh I get it now... you are reading the error I got from Chrome DevTools... that's not actual code. My code is `var param = {
                    dni: $scope.usuario.dni, 
                    contrasenia: $scope.usuario.contrasenia
            };` and it's written in _AngularJS_

Comment: Edited my anwer. You are Setting bad you varialbe in AngularJS. If you want to create a Json Object, then you need the right format. I hope this solve the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: You were right... I was trying with single quotes and didn't try with doble quotes... So easy and so hard. Okay thanks @Gatusko I'll mark your answer as the correct one and I'll definetly will read your tutorial ;)

Comment: Thanks check this tutorial [javascript with JSon](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) too. This are common pitfalls and the sametime really hard to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set request header

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/login/check', param,{
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(){
    $state.go('login');
});
```

Comment: I tried this as you suggest, still gives me the same error. Any suggestions ? Maybe how can I enter a debug mode to see what's going on?